# Why Jupyter notebook is not starting after atp-get update on docker tensorflow image?

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I use tensorflow image: `docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow`

The Jupyter notebook is starting automatically: `[I 13:00:45.022 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: ...`

I use the next command to attach to docker instance: `docker run -i -t tensorflow/tensorflow /bin/bash`

After I run `apt-get update` on this instance the Jupyter Notebook is not starting anymore.

How can I fix it and why does it happen?

Comment: How do you run `apt-get update`? you use docker attach and then run this command?

Comment: yes, docker run -i -t tensorflow/tensorflow /bin/bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `docker run -i -t tensorflow/tensorflow /bin/bash` you do not attach a currently running container with the notebook server running inside. You launch another container based on the same image, but override the default start command, lauching the notebook server.

So, the easy solution for you is to run `/run_jupyter.sh --allow-root` after you've done what you wanted to do with your `apt-get update`.

The best solution would be to create another image based on tensorflow's where you would do the additional installations you need, and run containers from this new image.